# ASP.Net core WebAPI controller- 200 status code but no response

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have following controller in my web API:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class User_TaskController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUser_TaskRepository _taskRepository;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly WebAPIDataContext _context;

    //Controller
    public User_TaskController(IUser_TaskRepository taskRepository, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, WebAPIDataContext context)
    {
        _taskRepository = taskRepository;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
    }

    //Get methods
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User_Task> GetAll()
    {

        return _taskRepository.GetAll();
    }


    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("current")]
    public IActionResult GetCurrentUserTasks()
    {

        // Obtain stakeholderId
        var stakeholderId = this.GetStakeholderId();
        var userTasks = _taskRepository.GetUserTasks(stakeholderId);

        return new ObjectResult(userTasks);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTask")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        var item = _taskRepository.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }

    //Create
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] User_Task item)
    {

        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var stakeholderId = this.GetStakeholderId();


        _taskRepository.Add(item, stakeholderId);

        var itemToReturn = _taskRepository.Find(item.TaskId);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(itemToReturn);

    }

    private long GetStakeholderId()
    {
        string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
        long stakeholderId = 0;

        var users = _userManager.Users;
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            if (user.Email == currentUserId)
            {
                var idForStakeholder = user.Id;
                var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
                foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
                {
                    if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                    {
                        stakeholderId = stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                        return stakeholderId;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return stakeholderId;
    }

}
```

And corresponding repository:

```
public class User_TaskRepository : IUser_TaskRepository
{
    private readonly WebAPIDataContext _context;

    public User_TaskRepository(WebAPIDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    public IEnumerable<User_Task> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.User_Tasks.Include(task => task.Steps).ToList();
    }

    // Method that returns all the tasks of a specific user i.e. logged in used making the request
    public ICollection<User_Task> GetUserTasks(long stakeholderId)
    {

        var userTasks = _context.User_Tasks
            .Where(task => task.StakeholderId == stakeholderId).ToList();

        return userTasks;
    }

    public void Add(User_Task item , long stakeholderId)
    {
        item.StakeholderId = stakeholderId;   

       _context.User_Tasks.Add(item);
       _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public User_Task Find(long key)
    {
        return _context.User_Tasks.Include(task => task.Steps).FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskId == key);
    }


}

public interface IUser_TaskRepository
{
    void Add(User_Task item, long stakeholderId);
    IEnumerable<User_Task> GetAll();
    ICollection<User_Task> GetUserTasks(long stakeholderId);
    User_Task Find(long key);
}
```

**Problems**:

1. For create method the record is added to the database but I do not get any response in Postman.
2. For getting tasks for a specific users i.e. `GetCurrentUserTasks()` untill last line before return statement, I see the tasks fetched however it returns nothing and I still get status 200 Ok on my angular2 frontend. I tried removing [Authorize] header but no effect.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `ObjectResult(){}` I believe the inline changes are what you are looking for.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("current")]
public IActionResult GetCurrentUserTasks()
{
    var status = HttpStatus.Ok; //<< add

    // Obtain stakeholderId
    var stakeholderId = this.GetStakeholderId();
    var userTasks = _taskRepository.GetUserTasks(stakeholderId);

    if(userTasks == null)
       status = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;

    return new ObjectResult(userTasks){StatusCode = (int)status };
}
```

Below your method with changes included

```
//Create
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] User_Task item)
{
   var status = HttpStatusCode.Ok;
    if (item == null)
    {
        status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var stakeholderId = this.GetStakeholderId();


    _taskRepository.Add(item, stakeholderId);

    var itemToReturn = _taskRepository.Find(item.TaskId);
    if (itemToReturn == null)
    {
        status = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        return NotFound();
    }
    return new ObjectResult(itemToReturn){StatusCode = (int)status};

}
```

Now for `GetCurrentUserTasks()` method doesn't do what you are expecting equating `_userManager.GetUserId(User);` returns the USER's Id which is a GUID not an email therefore you logic in the for loop (why you are looping thru users, is a unusual step, useless really) kills the next loop structure.  This is all based on the assumption on my part that you are using a unaltered Identity setup for ASp.net Core.

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);  // << GUID
    long stakeholderId = 0;

    var users = _userManager.Users;       //<< pointless
    foreach (var user in users)           //   ^^^   
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)  << // will never be TRUE
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;
            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId = stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return stakeholderId;   // WILL ALWAYS be 0
}
```

I am pretty sure at this point from the code posted you will get a OK 200 from the `GetCurrentUserTasks()` because it does run but never pulls the tasks for the user since the user is never actually found correctly in the base of your code.

Comment: _userManager.GetUserId(User) returns me email indeed, email is my username, actually that's why I had to loop through twice.. Let me try your solution.

Comment: I tried it and for GetCurrentUserTasks it was still the same, I am getting the status code as 200 but no content from server :(

Comment: how are you authenticating?  I just tried it on my end and it shows up the GUID for the user as expected.  Are you authenticating with cookie or jwt?

Answer (score 0):

For your Create() method, it seems like you're checking if the "item" variable is null, then returning the "itemToReturn" variable, which is probably null (which is why you get an empty result):

```
   //Create
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] User_Task item)
    {

        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var stakeholderId = this.GetStakeholderId();


        _taskRepository.Add(item, stakeholderId);

        var itemToReturn = _taskRepository.Find(item.TaskId);
        if (item == null) // checking item instead of itemToReturn
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(itemToReturn);

    }
```

Shouldn't you be checking if "itemToReturn" is null?

Comment: The error was in my models somehow, when I removed navigation property of a user from Task (if you remember), it started displaying!